# Countibility of resolvent set in C* algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

I'm going through the topic $C^*$ algebra and facing few questions. It would be great if you people could help me to clear the doubts.

**Q3.** Does there exists some $X$ belonging to a $C^*$ algebra such that resolvent set is countable.

**Ans.** If suppose I consider the $n \times n$ matrix $M_n(C)$ as $C^*$ algebra then as the spectrum set is the set of Eigenvalues for any element in $M_n(C)$ , by definition resolvent set = C( complex number) - n ..so uncountable for all $x$ belongs to $M_n(C)$.

The question is, am I sounding correct ? If not please suggest a suitable example.

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum of any element of a Banach algebra is compact, so the resolvent set is always nonempty and open therefore uncountable.

Comment: Oh yes, in Euclidean topology  non empty open sets are always uncountable. Get it.